# Database structure for a customer shopkeeper website

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, distributed-databases

I am working on a project in which there will be two spaces for the customer and the shopkeeper. Multiple shopkeepers can insert data and can modify the products in their shop(they will have a unique id for their shop).The customer with their shop id-they have been assigned can see all the details about their shopkeeper and the available products in his shop.

I have made the database for the one shopkeeper's product details

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_desc` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `product_img_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

can somebody help me in the designing the database structure for my project any suggestions are welcomed for improving the efficiency?

Comment: Edit your title to describe the specifics of your question.

Comment: A "product code" is probably limited to much less than 60, correct?  Make `product_code` the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

## Foreign key

You forgot the foreign key field linking these records to the shop.

You need to add a column in this table here to store the primary key value of the shop who owns these products.

## Eliminate redundant data

If there is any chance of needing the product info elsewhere, or any chance of having one shopkeeper track more than one quantity of that product, the the product fields of code, name, description, and image should be moved to a separate parent table named `product` while this table is renamed something like `stock`. You would add a foreign key to link each child `stock` record to its parent `product` record.

You gave yourself a clue about this when you prefixed the names of these columns with “product_”.

## Other

Other points…

It appears that you are wrestling with [*multitenancy*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), the technical term for having various shopkeepers as your customers where each sees only a subset of the data, each handled as if the database were just for them yet having to be commingled with other shopkeepers. You may want to search on that term to learn some techniques and guidance.

No need to use quotes on your particular column names. Indeed, doing so can change the way the column name is stored in some databases.

You might want to stick with standard SQL data types and avoid proprietary ones such as `tinytext` in case you ever decide to move up to another database such as Postgres.

Your table name should be singular rather than plural, `product` rather than `products`, `shopkeeper` rather than `shopkeepers`, per [relational theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).

I do not know the specifics of MySQL, but robust databases handle Unicode, to store a wide range of possible cgaracters. So rather than specify Latin-1 as the character set, use something like [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) if MySQL is capable.